# Show Bootstrap 3 gray background without a modal box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on my own sidemenu nav which when used on a small screen should pop in and out.

I'd like the rest of the screen to turn gray, like what happens in Bootstrap 3 when a modal is displayed.

Is there any way to reuse the Bootstrap gray background for this purpose? In other words show/hide the gray background without a modal, using jQuery?

For purposes of this question, you can just imagine that on a blank HTML page I would like to display the gray background without any modal.

Thanks

Comment: Code please..!?

Comment: Hi @AbhishekPandey. I don't believe code is relevant for this question.

Comment: Yes, It is, otherwise how we can find out which example or piece of code is better suits with your code

Comment: For purposes of the question, you can assume just a blank HTML page (I've added this note to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've got your issues. It's just a 'class' that is responsible for the backdrop of gray background and the modal. The class needs to be present in the parent div.

## HTML

```
<div class="modal-backdrop">
   <div class="child-component"> 
      <div class ="panel"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.modal-backdrop {
    background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5) !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

You have to toggle class 'connect-modal-backdrop' with 'hide' class to show/hide the Modal.

Comment: Hi! With your answer it appears you are creating your own gray backdrop (with it's own CSS). Is there any way to reuse Bootstrap's css?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. For that , you need to use class name '.modal' instead of 'modal-backdrop'. And you also need to replace display property 'none' with  'block'. As Modal class has display property as none.